# iPad Landscape orientation

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios7, landscape-portrait

I am creating an App in portrait and Landscape Mode for iPad . I create a XIB in Landscape Mode for iPad but when i run that App it always shows in portrait Mode .
I set all setting under property list(.plist) file as "Supported Interface orientation(iPad)" and set Landscape(Left Home button) and landscape(Right Home Button) and also check the Orientation from the Code but all this doesn't work.
please help us if any one knows the exact problem or this , we are using Navigation Controller

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in delegate.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```

Then add following methods in delegate first and run the app, if fixed, COOOOL else add following four methods in each your view controller. You problem will be fixed.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Comment: I have done this things but it won't work , it still showing me Portrait mode only , Is there any settings in Interface Builder , i also uncheck the auto layout checkbox from interface builder

Comment: In your project settings which Device Orientations are enabled ? If both are enabled then this is how app will react.

Comment: Yes initially both orientation are enabled , now i set to only Landscape Mode , and now simulator display in Landscape mode but still my view and Text fields inside the View display in portrait